# Update an entity with one to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, one-to-many

I have a **Suppliers** table with the following schema:

```
| SupplierId | SupplierName |
-----------------------------
| 1          | Good Company |
```

I also have one-to-many table **SupplierActivityHours** with the following schema:

```
| Id | SupplierId | Day (enum) | OpenHour         | CloseHour        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 0          | 05:00:00.0000000 | 15:00:00.0000000 |
| 2  | 1          | 1          | 05:00:00.0000000 | 15:00:00.0000000 |
| 3  | 1          | 2          | 05:00:00.0000000 | 16:00:00.0000000 |
```

I created a settings page where each supplier can update its data.

**The question is**, what is the correct way to update the activity hours table?

The supplier may remove days, add days, update hours for existing days.

I thought about the following options:

1. When user submit updated data, I will remove all the rows from "SupplierActivityHours" table (all rows of specific supplier ofcourse)
   and then add the new values.
   The problem with this method is that its not efficient. What if user just update an hour in one of the days?
2. I will hold 3 lists on the client side

   - List of ids to remove
   - List of items to update (row id and updated data)
   - List of new items to add

      
     The problem with this method is that **I think** its a bit too complicated to such common action.

BTW, I'm working with ASP.NET MVC Core, MS SQL and Dapper.NET (if it matters somehow).

Is there any better option I'm not aware of? Thank you all!

---

### Update

I'm currently reading about "MERGE", trying to see if it may solve my problem.

Comment: When working with a shared database you can never keep data locally because another user could be changing the data.  So best way is to make changes in a stored procedure in the database which contains locks to prevent conflicts when more than one user access the same data.

Comment: Be wary of foreign keys just to have them. They are a hit on performance and deleting from the tables is a two step process (to prevent orphaned supplier_IDs).
If you setup your design correctly, you can avoid enforcing any key on the FACT table, which will improve performance long term. There is, after all, strengths and weaknesses to any approach.

Answer (score 2):

Right, you can use MERGE in this way:

```
create type SupplierActivityHoursType as table 
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SupplierId] [int] NULL,
    [Day] [int] NULL,
    [OpenHour] [datetime] NULL,
    [CloseHour] [datetime] NULL
)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSupplierActivityHours
    @SupplierActivityHours dbo.SupplierActivityHoursType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    merge SupplierActivityHours as t
    using (select Id, SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour  
           from @SupplierActivityHours) as s
    on t.Id = s.Id, t.SupplierId = s.SupplierId
    when matched then
        update set t.[Day] = s.[Day], t.OpenHour = s.OpenHour, t.CloseHour = s.CloseHour
    when not matched by  target then
        insert (SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour) 
            values (s.SupplierId, s.[Day], s.OpenHour, s.CloseHour)
    when not matched by source then
        delete;
END
```

So, to update all supplier data you need to pass to `UpdateSupplierActivityHours` SP your hours table.

When record is found in `SupplierActivityHours` it will be updated, when it is found in @SupplierActivityHours but not found in `SupplierActivityHours` table it will be inserted and if is not found in `@SupplierActivityHours` but found in `SupplierActivityHours` it will be deleted.

MERGE statement allows to perform all these inserts, updates and deletes in one transaction efficiently.

Comment: This is almost correct, but it will remove all other suppliers hours unless you modify the sp: WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND t.SupplierId = @SupplierId THEN DELETE, so we need to add one more parameter to sp and pass current supplier's id.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say the "wipe/update" method is not efficient it is the easiest to implement.

When you have multiple users editing the same data you either have to prevent others editing the table or tell them that the "last edit wins"; i.e. edits will be overwritten.

Whether this is a problem for your users is up to you, and dependent on the potential number of users editing the data at the same time - you may find it's never a problem.

If you are worried about losing edits you could implement an audit log of the data and record all the changes.

Comment: To be honest, i'm not worried about editing the same data in the same time. Its user's settings page. I'm not worried about case when user edits his settings from multiple machines in the same time, or an admin updating the data in the same time the user does.

Answer (score 0):

This table schema and pattern is one of the few instances in which I would consider dropping the surrogate `Id` as a primary key and consider using `SupplierId, Day` as my primary key. This version of the `merge` procedure ignores the `Id` anyhow. Unless you are also going to have queries getting or setting by rows by something other than `SupplierId, Day`, I do not see the need for `Id`.

In the end, I would recommend you do whatever you feel comfortable with concerning `Id`.

table setup:

```
create table dbo.Suppliers (
    SupplierId int primary key
  , SupplierName nvarchar(64)
);

insert into dbo.Suppliers values
(1, 'Good Company');

create table dbo.SupplierActivityHours (
    Id int not null
  , SupplierId int not null
  , [Day] tinyint not null
  , OpenHour time(0) not null
  , CloseHour time(0) not null
  , constraint pk_SupplierActivityHours primary key clustered (Id)
  , constraint fk_SupplierActivityHours_Suppliers foreign key (SupplierId)
      references Suppliers(SupplierId)
  );

create unique nonclustered index
  uix_SupplierActivityHours_SupplierId_Day
    on dbo.SupplierActivityHours (SupplierId, [Day])
      include (OpenHour, CloseHour);
/* If the Supplier can have multiple open/close per day,
 move OpenHour from the include() to the index key. */

insert into dbo.SupplierActivityHours values
    (1,1,0,'05:00:00.0000000','15:00:00.0000000')
  , (2,1,1,'05:00:00.0000000','15:00:00.0000000')
  , (3,1,2,'05:00:00.0000000','16:00:00.0000000');
```

table type:

```
create type dbo.udt_SupplierActivityHours as table (
  /* You will not have an ID for new rows, so no need for it here */
    SupplierId int not null
  , [Day] tinyint not null
  , OpenHour time(0) not null
  , CloseHour time(0) not null
  , unique (SupplierId,[Day]) /* unnamed unique constraint */
  --, primary key clustered (SupplierId, [Day]) /* instead of unique constraint */
  /* If the Supplier can have multiple open/close per day,
     add OpenHour to the unique constraint or primary key. */
);
```

merge procedure:

```
go
create procedure dbo.SupplierActivityHours_Merge (
    @SupplierActivityHours dbo.udt_SupplierActivityHours readonly
) as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on; /* you should always include this. */
  begin try
    begin tran
      merge SupplierActivityHours with (holdlock) as t
        /* with (holdlock) prevents race conditions in merge */
      using (select SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour
             from @SupplierActivityHours) as s
        on t.SupplierId = s.SupplierId
          and t.[Day] = s.[Day]
      when matched and (
             t.OpenHour  != s.OpenHour
          or t.CloseHour != s.CloseHour
      )
        then
          update set
              t.OpenHour  = s.OpenHour
            , t.CloseHour = s.CloseHour
      when not matched by target
        then insert (SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour)
          values (s.SupplierId, s.[Day], s.OpenHour, s.CloseHour)
      when not matched by source then
          delete
          /* check output for testing: */
          --output $action, deleted.*, inserted.*, s.*
          ;
    commit tran
  end try
  begin catch;
    if @@trancount > 0
      begin;
        rollback transaction;
        throw; /* or other error handling */
      end;
  end catch;
end;
go
```

In the above table type, I have included a unique constraint to prevent duplicates. The unique constraint will incur some overhead. If that overhead is a concern and you have other safeguards in place to prevent issues with incoming data, remove it.

An alternative to the unique constraint is to use a primary key clustered on the table type, this also incurs overhead. There are ways to mitigate some of that overhead by guaranteeing that data is added to it already ordered from the application, but it gets pretty involved.

Why you should always include [`set nocount, xact_abort on;` - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT)

Things you should be aware of when using `merge`:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server `MERGE` Statement - Aaron Bertrand](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)
- [UPSERT Race Condition With `Merge` - sqlteam](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)
- [An Interesting `MERGE` Bug - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/03/another-interesting-merge-bug.aspx)
- [The Case of the Blocking `Merge` Statement (LCK_M_RS_U locks) - Kendra Little](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/05/24/the-case-of-the-blocking-merge-statement-lck_m_rs_u-locks/)
- [Writing t-sql `merge` statements the right way - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/05/writing-t-sql-merge-statements-the-right-way/)

Table-Valued Parameters reference:

- [Table-Valued Parameters - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)

---

Here is an example of how you could do the three part operation instead of a `merge`. Hopefully this will seem less complicated than what you had intended:

```
create type dbo.udt_ActivityHours as table (
    [Day] tinyint not null
  , OpenHour time(0) not null
  , CloseHour time(0) not null
  , unique ([Day])
  -- If the Supplier can have multiple open/close per day,
  -- add OpenHour to the unique constraint or primary key
);

go
create procedure dbo.SupplierActivityHours_Set_BySupplierId (
    @SupplierId int not null
  , @ActivityHours dbo.udt_ActivityHours readonly
) as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on; -- you should always use these.
  begin try
    begin tran

    /* delete */
      delete sah 
        from dbo.SupplierActivityHours sah
          where sah.SupplierId = @SupplierId
            and not exists (
              select 1 
                from @ActivityHours ah
                  where ah.[Day] = sah.[Day]
                );

    /* update */
      update sah set 
          sah.OpenHour  = ah.OpenHour
        , sah.CloseHour = ah.CloseHour
        from SupplierActivityHours sah
          inner join @ActivityHours ah on sah.[Day] = ah.[Day]
           and sah.SupplierId = @SupplierId
        where sah.OpenHour  != ah.OpenHour
           or sah.CloseHour != ah.CloseHour;

    /* insert */
      insert into dbo.SupplierActivityHours 
                (SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour)
         select @SupplierId, [Day], OpenHour, CloseHour
          from @ActivityHours ah
          where not exists (
              select 1 
                from dbo.SupplierActivityHours sah 
                  where sah.SupplierId = @SupplierId
                    and ah.[Day] = sah.[Day]
                );

    commit tran;
  end try
  begin catch;
    if @@trancount > 0 
      begin;
        rollback transaction;
        throw; 
      end;
  end catch;
end;
go
```

TVPs seem to cause deadlocks on rextester, so the rextester uses a temp table stand-in.  ([tvp deadlock example](http://rextester.com/DTVOU28940))

rextester: http://rextester.com/DCUPNF63408

Answer (score 0):

First, lets recall SQL is a `relational set-based theory`, so it stands the database and its solutions are meaningful with relational value to **everything**.
This also leads us to think holistically, both with the network traffic involved and the impact on the database, fragmentation, and so on. Nothing is wasted in our design.

Also, `Schemas` in `SQL Server` are equivalent to a `tablespace` in `Oracle`, or like a Housing Association in a city of houses. Schemas have their own security and contain multiple tables. Tables contain multiple columns.

YOUR TABLE DESIGN

```
/*---------------------------------
|   DIMENSION - dbo.Suppliers
*--------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE dbo.Suppliers (Supplier_ID INT NOT NULL
                          , Supplier_Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
/*---------------------------------
|   FACT - dbo.ActivityHours_Suppliers
*--------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE dbo.ActivityHours_Suppliers
                         (  Row_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
/* At best a database key, but your design makes it useless.*/
                         ,  Supplier_ID INT NOT NULL
/* Value, whether you have a constraint or not comes from dbo.Suppliers*/
                         ,  Day_enum INT
/* Is this a Durable Key?*/
                         ,  OpenHour  TIME NOT NULL
                         ,  CloseHour TIME NOT NULL)
```

Accordingly, you wish to reflect changes in this FACT table with the following situations:

1. `UPDATE` ActivityHours_Suppliers table on values OpenHour, CloseHour
2. `INSERT` ActivityHours_Suppliers table Day_enum, OpenHour, CloseHour?
3. `DELETE` from ActivityHours_Suppliers where Day_enum is illegitimate.
   -- although this latter problem should be handled before it hits the database.

Observations and Questions:

- **Does your Day_enum column count forwards in perpetuity?**

If yes, you have just created a [durable key](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/07/design-tip-147-durable-super-natural-keys/). If no, consider using another column to allow for future distinctions to be made. Though, I would prefer this is separate from the clients control

- **When do these Changes occur?**

At the beginning of the day? At intervals? At the end of the Day? Live (probably not)? If not at the end of the day or before the beginning, will you allow for NULL values in CloseHour? This might make the update easier.

- **What you need is a Staging Table.**

Staging Tables are better long-term solutions and make managing the insertions/updates much easier on the system since you are using a set-based solution.

Especially if you are not planning on real-time, Staging Tables will act as another buffer before hitting the database.

- **Supplier_ID should be automatically entered.**

Perhaps via the GUI the secretary is using that references the DIM table. Make the option to create a new supplier SEPARATE from this. You want this to never be at fault.

You could....could use two tables, one for updating and one for inserting, but since this is a staging table, does it matter? Are you doing anything to these tables that would necessitate two separate tables?

**Your StagingTable, then, holds the following values**:
    `Supplier_ID, Day_enum, OpenHour, CloseHour`.

- **MERGE is an expensive process.**

If you think you have lots of rows inserted and deleted everytime, then consider its benefits at stream-lining large modifications of table rows.

If your amount varies, then perhaps a mix of MERGE and CTEs would be appropriate (which is an easy check) `IF <someNumber> < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TempTable)`

```
/*---------------------------------
|       UPDATING FIELDS
*--------------------------------*/
WITH CTE AS (SELECT Supplier_ID, Day_enum, OpenHour, CloseHour
             FROM TempTable)

UPDATE A
    SET OpenHour = B.OpenHour
      , CloseHour = C.CloseHour
    FROM MYTABLE A
    INNER JOIN CTE B ON B.Supplier_ID = A.Supplier_ID
                    AND B.Day_enum = B.Day_enum

/*---------------------------------
|       INSERTING FIELDS
*--------------------------------*/
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT Supplier_ID, Day_enum
             FROM dbo.Suppliers
              --use this as an opportunity to filter the rows or not at all)

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (Supplier_ID, Day_enum, OpenHour, CloseHour)
SELECT Supplier_ID, Day_enum, OpenHour, CloseHour
FROM TempTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM CTE
                  WHERE ROWS = TempTable.ROWS)
```

(NOT) EXISTS returns a true or false value, so we do not need to specify the columns in the SELECT statement.
OR you can limit the impact to sections    ...perhaps regional, states, cities, whatever like the following

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT A.Supplier_ID, A.Day_enum, A.OpenHour, A.CloseHour
             FROM TempTable A
             INNER JOIN dbo.Suppliers B ON B.Supplier_ID = A.Supplier_ID
                                       AND B.Day_enum = A.Day_Enum
             WHERE A.Day_enum > (somenumber)
             -- A.Day_enum IS NOT NULL
                 )
```

Even better, consider replacing the SupplierTable with a Subquery that limits the DIM table to these sections, regions, whatever like the following

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT Supplier_ID, Day_enum
            FROM dbo.Suppliers
            WHERE Region_ID = 15
                AND Region_ID = 20) AS B ON B.Supplier_ID = A.Supplier_ID
                                       AND B.Day_enum = A.Day_Enum
             WHERE A.Day_enum IS NOT NULL
```

/* You might even find this type of JOIN effective for your database */

```
SELECT A.Supplier_ID, A.Day_enum, A.OpenHour, A.CloseHour
FROM MYINSERT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ActivityHours_Suppliers B ON A.Supplier_ID = B.Supplier_ID 
                         AND A.Day_enum = B.Day_enum
WHERE A.Day_enum IS NOT NULL
```

This will return every row that matches on the left side and filter out every row that is NULL, thus giving you only rows that need to be inserted.

Finally, always test, as the size and scope of your tables can dictate what is really a solution or not.

I hope I gave you a lot to consider and helped you on your way to providing a long-term solution!

*Sources:*
KimballGroup (07/2012). [Durable Super-Natural Keys](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/07/design-tip-147-durable-super-natural-keys/)

Comment: Note that the Kimball and Inmon methods all have their strengths and weaknesses. What I am aiming for is how this solution can make your life easier, especially at maintenance where most of the time and energy ends at.

Comment: Edited Post for consistency.